# Add a keys() method on Object globally

Tags: javascript, object, methods, prototype

I'm trying to make a method on all objects:

Can have this result:

```
var obj = {'first_name': 'Alfred', 'last_name': 'Huang', 'age': 27, };
print(obj.myKeys());  // echos: ['age', 'first_name', 'last_name'];
```

I wrote the code as below (using technique from the book ):

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
    if(!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
    }
};

Object.method('myKeys', function() {
    var i, result = [];
    for(i in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result.sort();
});
```

And the method works on my computer, but it seemed collides with other components, so cannot even run in the fiddle, and the `jQyery` library is affected.

So what's the matter? Can anyone point it out and tell me how to get it right, I just want to make a `keys` function to get the sorted keys of an object.

Comment: Don't forget about [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: This is generally a Bad Idea because any for...in loops that do not guard with `hasOwnProperty` will iterate over this function you are adding, which is probably not what you will want.  As Jesse said, use `Object.keys` if your target platforms support it (basically everything but IE < 9), otherwise consider writing a separate utility function not hung off of `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Objects don't have order, so sorting the keys would not be very effective.

Comment: I tried to rename the `keys` function to 'myKeys', but the code seemed still collides.